# How to run a script on startup in hidden mode

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, windows-8.1, startup

I have a batch file, named `prova.bat`, and I need to launch it at the startup of the computer, and I need to launch it in hidden mode (with no visible prompt).

I have found on the net solutions to launch the batch at the startup OR solutions to launch the batch in hidden mode, but not solutions to fix both my problems. I have tried with a VBScript and set the script to run at the startup (in the SystemConfiguration).

The OS where the batch have to run is Windows 8.1.

Here's the content of the VBScript (maybe it's something wrong in it):

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\app\app\prova.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284876/what-are-the-different-ways-to-start-a-hidden-process-with-batch-file-and-what-a

Comment: on windos 8* startup folder is located in `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: The VBScript should do what you want, so your problem is most likely with how you configured its autostart. Where "in the system configuration" did  you configure it to "run at the startup" (startup of what?)?

Comment: Do you mean "on startup" or "on login"?

Comment: check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/641150/how-to-run-a-process-in-the-background-without-keeping-a-batch-file-open/872858#872858) and [this](https://superuser.com/a/1187025/62798)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Vbscript can did the trick **(Tested on Windows 7 32 bits)**

Hope will work on your **Windows 8** ;)

So the code is very easy to use : You just change two things on it :

- **PathApplication**
- **ShortcutName**

---

```
Option Explicit
Dim PathApplication,ShortcutName,VbsPath
VbsPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
PathApplication = "C:\signcatcher\signcatcher\prova.bat"
ShortcutName = "Hackoo"
Call Shortcut(VbsPath,ShortcutName)
Call Hidden_Run(Dblquote(PathApplication))
'*********************************************************************************
Sub Shortcut(PathApplication,ShortcutName)
    Dim objShell,StartFolder,objShortCut,MyTab
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    MyTab = Split(PathApplication,"\")
    If ShortcutName = "" Then
        ShortcutName = MyTab(UBound(MyTab))
    End if
    StartFolder = objShell.SpecialFolders("Startup")
    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(StartFolder & "\" & ShortcutName & ".lnk")
    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote(PathApplication)
    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll,-25"
    objShortCut.Save
End Sub
'*********************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'*********************************************************************************
Function Hidden_Run(MyProgram)
    Dim ws,Result
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Result = ws.run(MyProgram,0,True) '0 to hide the program
    Hidden_Run = Result
End Function
'*********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer, I've made a shortcut and put it in the startup folder, I have to put in that folder even this vbscript? Or i have to put in in another folder (the vbscript in my question was short and i have put it in the system register)

Comment: @Luca89 Did you tried this vbscript below or not yet ? because i make it very easy to use just change the path of your batch and (the name of shortcut is optional) and the vbscript can do the rest

Comment: I have tried to run the vbscript manually and its start my java application.
I need that the application starts at the startup of the computer, I have to put the vbscript in the startup folder of windows 8.1?

Comment: I said below that this vbscript can create a shortcut and can launch your java application if of course if you modifie this line : PathApplication = "C:\signcatcher\signcatcher\prova.bat" by your path of java application
so you don't need to do it manually !

Comment: Is there a method for launch this script in Admin mode?
Like a check/modify user before call Hidden_Run or something else?

Comment: What problem does this script solve, that cannot be done using a [registry file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-files) (without user-supplied code that is subject to bugs)?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to use start up folder - `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.You can choose a method to start your batch in hidden/background mode.Probably best choice is [win32process](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/wsh/win32process.bat) as it offers a lot of options.So just put a script in start up folder a script like:

```
@call  "c:\tools\win32process.bat" "C:\signcatcher\signcatcher\prova.bat" -showWindows 0 -directory "C:\signcatcher\signcatcher"
```

where you'll have to change the actual path to win32process.bat

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer, I have tried this solution bat on the pc there is no win32process.bat (or maybe I was not able to find it)

Comment: @Luca89 - you need to download it from the link.