# Why does VBS always tell me file not found even though the file is right there? (At startup)

Tags: vbscript, startup

I have a .vbs file, which I have set to run at startup through regedit. Basically what the vbs does, is execute another program in the same directory (I will paste the vbs script below). Normally, the vbs script works great and everything is good. However, whenever the vbs script run at startup (i.e auto running right after the computer is booted), I always get a error message, telling me that Windows cannot find my file (i.e hello.exe), even though the exe file is right there.

I have tried setting a delay to the script, but that resulted in the same problem. I am extremely confused because everytime I run the vbs manually (like double click it), everything works fine, no problem.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "hello.exe" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

The expected result is that the vbs script will just run normally, like how it runs everytime i manually launch it. The error message is "Line 2: File cannot be found", or something along the lines of that.

Comment: Have you set the "Start in" option set to the correct directory in your scheduled task?

Comment: @Tomalak Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think I set it up through regedit, not task scheduler. I just double checked and i can't see anything in task schedule

Comment: Where is excatly the location of your .exe file ?

Comment: *"I think I set it up through regedit"* - How? By placing it in the "Autorun" key? Have you tried using the task scheduler instead?

Comment: @Leo Feng Take a look at this [How to run a script on startup un hidden mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671266/how-to-run-a-script-on-startup-in-hidden-mode/30677140?r=SearchResults#30677140)

Answer (score 1):

As Hackoo is getting to, use the full path to the EXE you are running:

`WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\My Hello App\hello.exe" & Chr(34), 0`

Answer (score 0):

This will run the exe file if its in the same folder as your script.

```
strPath = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName,"\"))
WshShell.Run chr(34) & strPath & "hello.exe" & Chr(34), 0
```